# How to refer to a mutated variable within ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to refer to a variable within ggplot which has been calculated using mutate from the dplyr package. The data.frame is then piped directly to ggplot. 
I think it becomes clear from the code below:

```
    dplyr::mutate(cars, speed2 = speed/mean(speed)) %>% 
     ggplot( ., aes(speed, dist)) +
      geom_point() + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(speed2))
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your mapping within `aes`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dplyr::mutate(cars, speed2 = speed/mean(speed)) %>% 
  ggplot( ., aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(speed2)))
```

[image]

Comment: It can be simplified to `cars %>% mutate(speed2 = speed/mean(speed)) %>% ggplot(aes(speed, dist)) %>%` etc.